run kubernets service on another device
i have app for calc and when i run it on my device (on html script with minikube ip and port of the service ) its work but when i run on another device its say the service its not get it
i try to run kubernets service on another device and i not get it .
how i can make the minikube ip availbe for any device and the port ,
all the service on nodeport
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Calculator</title>
<style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
    .container {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    .input-field {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .btn {
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #007bff;
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 17px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .btn:hover {
        background-color: #0056b3;
    }
    .fonts {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .fonts .btn{
        width: 48%;
    }
    .operations-div{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
        gap: 10px;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .pyOperations-div{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
        gap: 10px;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .pyOperations-div .btn{
        background-color: #007bff;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .pyOperations-div .btn:hover {
        background-color: #0056b3;
    }

    .nodeOperations-div{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
        gap: 10px;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .nodeOperations-div .btn{
        background-color: #8BC500;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .nodeOperations-div .btn:hover {
        background-color: #3f804c;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="input-field">
        <label for="num1">Enter first number:</label>
        <input type="number" id="num1">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <label for="num2">Enter second number:</label>
        <input type="number" id="num2">
    </div>
    <div class="operations-div">
        <div class="pyOperations-div">
        <button class="btn" onclick="performAddOperation()">+</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="performSubstractOperation()">-</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="performMultiplyOperation()">*</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="performDivideOperation()">/</button>
    </div>
        <div class="nodeOperations-div">
            <button class="btn" onclick="performNodeAddOperation()">+</button>
            <button class="btn" onclick="performNodeSubstractOperation()">-</button>
            <button class="btn" onclick="performNodeMultiplyOperation()">*</button>
            <button class="btn" onclick="performNodeDivideOperation()">/</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn" onclick="performEnglishOperation()">English</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="performHebrewOperation()">Hebrew</button>
        
    <div class="fonts">
        <button class="btn" onclick="sizeResultFontSize('increase')">Increase Result Font Size</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="sizeResultFontSize('decrease')">Decrease Result Font Size</button>
    </div>

    <button class="btn" onclick="resultRandomColor()">Result random color</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var ip = 'http://172.20.3.181'
    function performAddOperation(){
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        if(!num1 || !num2){
        alert("Error: fields can't be empty")
            return null;
        }


        var url = `${ip}:30661/add?num1=${num1}&num2=${num2}`;
       
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + data.result;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert("Error: this service is not available now");
        });
    }

    function performSubstractOperation(){
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        if(!num1 || !num2){
        alert("Error: fields can't be empty")
            return null;
        }

        var url = `${ip}:32062/subtract?num1=${num1}&num2=${num2}`;

        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + data.result;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert("Error: this service is not available now");
        });
    }

    function performMultiplyOperation(){
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        if(!num1 || !num2){
        alert("Error: fields can't be empty")
            return null;
        }

        var url = `${ip}:32374/multiply?num1=${num1}&num2=${num2}`;

        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + data.result;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert("Error: this service is not available now");
        });
    }

    function performDivideOperation(){
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        if(!num1 || !num2){
        alert("Error: fields can't be empty")
            return null;
        }

        var url = `${ip}:32262/divide?num1=${num1}&num2=${num2}`;

        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + data.result;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert("Error: this service is not available now");
        });
    }

    function performNodeAddOperation(){
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        if (!num1 || !num2) {
            alert("Error: fields can't be empty");
            return null;
        }
       
        var url = ip +':30674/add?num1=' + num1 + '&num2=' + num2;

        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + data.result;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert("Error: this service is not available now");
            });
    }
    
    function performNodeSubstractOperation(){
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        if (!num1 || !num2) {
            alert("Error: fields can't be empty");
            return null;
        }

        var url = `${ip}:31841/subtract?num1=${num1}&num2=${num2}`;

        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + data.result;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert("Error: this service is not available now");
            });
    }
        
    function performNodeMultiplyOperation(){
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        if (!num1 || !num2) {
            alert("Error: fields can't be empty");
            return null;
        }

        var url = `${ip}:31952/multiply?num1=${num1}&num2=${num2}`;

        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + data.result;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert("Error: this service is not available now");
            });
    }
    
    function performNodeDivideOperation(){
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        if (!num1 || !num2) {
            alert("Error: fields can't be empty");
            return null;
        }

        var url = `${ip}:32262/divide?num1=${num1}&num2=${num2}`;

        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + data.result;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert("Error: this service is not available now");
            });
    }
    
    function performEnglishOperation() {
        var res = document.getElementById("result").innerText;
        var res = res.split(" ")[1];

        if (!res) {
            alert("Error: you must calculate something before");
            return null;
        } else if (isNaN(Number(res))) {
            alert("Error: result must be a number for this function");
            return null;
        }

        var url = `${ip}:30621/english?result=${res}`;

        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + data.result_english;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert("Error: this service is not available now");
        });
    }


    function performHebrewOperation() {
        var res = document.getElementById("result").innerText;
        var res = res.split(" ")[1];

        if (!res) {
            alert("Error: you must calculate something before");
            return null;
        } else if (isNaN(Number(res))) {
            alert("Error: result must be a number for this function");
            return null;
        }

        var url = `${ip}:32696/hebrew?result=${res}`;

        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + data.result_hebrew;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert("Error: this service is not available now");
        });
    }


    function sizeResultFontSize(type) {
        var res = document.getElementById("result");
        var currentFontSize = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(res).getPropertyValue('font-size'));

        var url = `${ip}:30861/${type}?fontSize=${currentFontSize}`;

        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            res.style.fontSize =  data.result + 'px';
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert("Error: this service is not available now");
        });
    }

    function resultRandomColor(){
        var res = document.getElementById("result");

        fetch(`${ip}:32286/randomColor`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            res.style.color =  data.result;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert("Error: this service is not available now");
        });
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>


